If the user clicks on the page while some JS code is running, what exactly does the browser do?
Suppose you have a button with an event listener that has a very long execution time. For the sake of simplicity, let’s just take this code as an example.
HTML
<div>
  <button>Click this</button>
</div>

JS
function sleep(millis) {
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < millis);
}

addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    sleep(2000);
    e.target.parentElement.innerHTML = "Clicked";
  });
});

I have noticed that in this example if you make a double click in the middle of the button, you end up with the “Clicked” text selected.
So if I understand correctly, if the user makes a double click, the browser does not queue another click event for the button. Instead, it only records the coordinates of the click, and processes it later, after the JavaScript code that is currently being ran finishes. So, for example, if at that time there is another button, then the click event of that button is going to fire.
Is this correct?
Is this behaviour consistent among all major browsers?
Are there any sources where this is documented in detail?
Here is another example.
JS
function sleep(millis) {
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < millis);
}

addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    sleep(2000);
    e.target.parentElement.innerHTML = "<button>BUTTON 2</button>";
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      const p = document.createElement("P");
      p.innerHTML = "CLICKED BUTTON 2";
        e.target.parentElement.append(p);
    })
  });
});

In this case, instead of text we are showing a second button.
And if user makes a double click, then the second button receives the second click after the handler of the first button has finished execution.
So, if you click two times, you end up with the second button and the “CLICKED BUTTON 2” text.
As pointed out by James, there has been a similar question before, however, the only answer to that question does not really address everything asked here.
In particular, I would like to know if I understand correctly that the browser does not really queue second click event for that button, and instead only registers that there was a click event with particular coordinates.
If this is correct, I would also like to know if there is particular documentation that can confirm this.

Aside from this actual question, the issue should be moot. You should structure your code so that any long-running operations are executed asynchronously so that the UI does not freeze

If you really have a "ui blocking" function that continuously has to do something intensive without interruption, then you should put that code in a web-worker.  That way the rest of your UI can function normally.

see also

You should learn about promises

OK, so you mentioned it yourself that the provided answer is not quite correct. I think it will benefit Stack Overflow if someone who actually has a good understanding of browsers handling events will provide an answer here that will be more correct. This can certainly benefit users coming from an Internet search.
